# Slick: Pass in column to update

Tags: sql, database, scala, slick

Let's say we have a FoodTable with the following columns: `Name`, `Calories`, `Carbs`, `Protein`. I have an entry for `Name = Chocolate`, `Calories = 100`, `Carbs = "10g"`, and `Protein = "2g"`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to pass in a column name and a new value to update with. For example, I want a method that's like

```
def updateFood(food, columnName, value):
     table.filter(_.name === food).map(x => x.columnName).update(value)
```

It seems like dynamic columns are not possible with Slick? I want to avoid writing a SQL query because that could lead to security flaws or bugs in the code. Is there really no way to do this?

I also don't want to have to pass in the entire object to update, since ideally, it should be:

I want to update column X to value Y. I should only need to pass in the id of the object, the column, and the value to update to.

Comment: I would like to suggest that this is an idiomatically wrong approach (pass column name and column value) since you are losing type safety in this case. Which is as bad as construct SQL query.
I have no idea what is your entity looks like, but maybe you can stay with some reasonable amount of update methods for every field in your DAO?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there's a way to pass in a column name and a new value to update with

This depends a little bit on what you want the "column name" to be. To maintain safety, what I'd suggest is having the "column name" be a function that can select a column in your table.

At a high level that would look like this:

```
// Won't compile, but we'll fix that in a moment
def updateFood[V](food: Food, column: FoodTable => Rep[V], value: V): DBIO[Int] =
  foods.filter(_.name === food.name).map(column).update(value)
```

...which we'd call like this:

```
updateFood(choc, _.calories, 99)
```

Notice how the "column name" is a function from `FoodTable` to a column of some value `V`.  Then you provide a value for the `V` and we do a normal update.

The problem is that Slick knows how to map certain types of values (String, Int, etc) into SQL, but not *any* kind of value. And the code above won't compile because `V` is unconstrained.

We can sort of fix that my adding a constraint on `V`, and it mostly will work:

```
// Will compile, will work for basic types
def updateFood[V : slick.ast.BaseTypedType](food: Food, column: FoodTable => Rep[V], value: V): DBIO[Int] =
 foods.filter(_.name === food.name).map(column).update(value)
```

However, if you have custom column mappings, they won't match the constraint. We need to go another step on and have an implicit shape in scope:

```
def updateFood[V](food: Food, column: FoodTable => Rep[V], value: V)(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, Rep[V], V, _]): DBIO[Int] =
 foods.filter(_.name === food.name).map(column).update(value)
```

I think of `Shape` as an extra level of abstraction in Slick, above `Rep[V]`. The mechanisms of the "shape levels" and other details are not something I can explain because I don't understand them yet! (There is a talk that goes into the design of Slick called "Polymorphic Record Types in a Lifted Embedding" which you can find at http://slick.lightbend.com/docs/)

A final note: if you really want the column name to be a String or something like that, I'd suggest pattern matching the string (or validate in some way) to a `FoodTable => Rep` function and use that in your SQL. That's going to be tricky because your value `V` is going to have to match the type of the column you want to update.

Off the top of my head, that could look something like this:

```
def tryUpdateFood(food: Food, columnName: String, value: String): DBIO[Int] =
 columnName match {
   case "calories" => updateFood(food, _.calories, value.toInt)
   case "carbs" => updateFood(food, _.carbs, value)
   // etc...
   case unknown => DBIO.failed(new Exception(s"Don't know how to update $unknown columns"))
}
```

I can imagine better error handling, safer or smarter parsing of the value, but in outline the above could work.

For hints at other ways to approach dynamic problems, take a look at the talk "Patterns for Slick database applications" (also listed at: http://slick.lightbend.com/docs/), and towards the end of the presentation there's a section on "Dynamic sorting".